# Django : execute command collectstatic raise UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, apache, static

Why raise UnicodeDecodeError?
I try to deploy my django app using apache
to copy static files, typing

```
$python manage.py collectstatic
```

and I got error message like below.

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs
collected = self.collect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 104, in collect
for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 137, in list
for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 37, in get_files
for fn in get_files(storage, ignore_patterns, dir):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 37, in get_files
for fn in get_files(storage, ignore_patterns, dir):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 25, in get_files
directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 236, in listdir
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, entry)):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 71, in join
path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's wrong with my static files?
my settings.py

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

and apache host conf

```
ServerName www.abcd.org
DocumentRoot /srv/www/yyy

<Directory /srv/www/yyy>
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess yyy.djangoserver processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup iii.djangoserver

WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/yyy/apache/django.wsgi
```

Comment: What's the value of `PROJECT_ROOT`; e.g. the path to your project? It contains a non-ASCII character.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's my project's name. and it not contains non-ASCII char. I changed it by '/srv/www/yyy/static/' but error continue to raise.

Comment: Well, it's your project name *plus it's absolute path*. But your test to set it to another path altogether shows that the next logical step is to check the static files themselves. Something there then contains a non-ASCII character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like one or more paths to your static files that are going to be copied contains non ASCII characters.

It has nothing to do with the path to the desctination directory.

**One way to find out would be** to put

```
try:
    print path
except:
    pass
try:
    print entry
except:
    pass
```

just before line 236 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py for a moment and then run manage.py again.

Then you should see where the problem occurs (you won't see the very culprit but the file just before it and propably directory of the problematic file).

**Or, alternatively, you can use pdb**:

```
python -m pdb manage.py collectstatic
```

and check which file is causing the problem in debugger.

Comment: I know this is an old question but what is at line 236? I am facing the same problem at the moment.

Comment: You can actually see it in the stacktrace shown in the question - a call to os package function that passed a str that then could not be decoded to Unicode with ascii decoder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I used **django-pipeline** inside docker container. It turned out that for some reason the system used POSIX locale. I used the solution proposed here and exported locale setting in system shell:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

You can check that afterwards your locale should be like:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/project$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

It worked well. Also, notice I did that both in docker and outside machine.