# UnicodeDecodeError Django Error Collectstatic

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-staticfiles

i have a problem.
I use collectstatic for production.
But i have this problem with a css file.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 240647: invalid continuation byte

But, i don't know why.

This is the traceback:

```
Post-processed 'tiempo_turco/stylesheets/foundation.css' as 'tiempo_turco/stylesheets/foundation.6f8a1d5c4dbc.css'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 173, in handle_noargs
collected = self.collect()
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 119, in collect
for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
File "/home/tulipan/Proyectos/IspanyolHaber/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 251, in post_process
content = original_file.read().decode(settings.FILE_CHARSET)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 240647: invalid continuation byte
```

Thank you very much for your help!

UPDATE:

I try fix it deleting this css file, but, i deleted and i have the same error, i don't understand why!

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS file is encoded as UTF8? It appears not to be.

Comment: The utf8 codec is seeing a continuation character (0xe1) in the CSS file which it expects is part of a UTF8 byte sequence. Confirm that the CSS file is the problem by replacing it with a simpler file containing ASCII only (a subset of UTF8). Look in the file around byte 240647.

Comment: Type the following into your python interpreter (you might need the full path to the css file): `open('tiempo_turco/stylesheets/foundation.css').read()[240645:240650]` - what is displayed?

Comment: Yes... you need to use Python - it's not a bash script. Anyway look at my answer which guesses at the CSS file's encoding and converts it to UTF8.

Comment: >>> open("foundation.css").read()[240645:240650]
''
>>> open('foundation.css').read()[240645:240650]
''
>>>

Comment: I try this now:
>>> open('statics/static/tiempo_turco/stylesheets/foundation.css')
<open file 'statics/static/tiempo_turco/stylesheets/foundation.css', mode 'r' at 0x7fc9b00884b0>

Comment: I think you are beyond help. Please follow the code and/or bash commands provided.

Comment: Forget it, the problem was a file with an á character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your CSS file is not really encoded as UTF8, most likely it is ISO-8859-1 in which the byte 0xE1 equates to `á` (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE). You can check the file type with the `file` command, and then convert it to UTF8 using `iconv`:

```
$ cp tiempo_turco/stylesheets/foundation.css /tmp
$ file /tmp/foundation.css
/tmp/foundation.css: ISO-8859 text
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF8  /tmp/foundation.css >/tmp/foundation_utf8.css
$ file /tmp/foundation_utf8.css
/tmp/foundation_utf8.css: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Not sure about how to update the file in your installation - you said that you tried removing it without any change, so maybe you need to restart your server?

If you don't have `iconv` you can convert it to UTF8 in Python:

```
$ python
>>> css = open('/tmp/foundation.css').read().decode('iso-8859-1')
>>> open('/tmp/foundation_utf8.css', 'w').write(css.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: If it really is ASCII then you should have no UTF8 decoding issues. Can you make your CSS file available somewhere? e.g. pastebin.com

Comment: My brother, i find finally the error, are in other file, app.css, i found it using the code here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915432/django-execute-command-collectstatic-raise-unicodedecodeerror

The first answer.

Comment: The code i put before this:
`# ..to apply each replacement pattern to the content
                if name in adjustable_paths:`
In the line 249 in the file.

And print me what is file error, and voila, i used your commands:

`>>> open('statics/static/tiempo_turco/stylesheets/app.css').read()[240645:240650]
' P\xe1gi'
>>> open('statics/static/tiempo_turco/stylesheets/app.css').read()[240605:240650]
';\n}\n\n/* Estilos de Slider de Noticias en P\xe1gi'`
Yes, i search in this file and changed bad character and works!!!
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, the problem is it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I used **django-pipeline** inside docker container. It turned out that for some reason the system used POSIX locale. I used the solution proposed [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline/issues/242) and exported locale setting in system shell:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

It worked well. Also, notice I did that both in docker and outside machine.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a good function for converting strings to unicode.  Try out this function

```
from from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

smart_unicode(value)
```

Comment: when you save the css file use this when your are writing a string to the file... write(smart_unicode(s))